# How to separate List elements with commas in Groovy?

Tags: list, groovy

```
def names = ["myname", "yourname", "theirname", "allnames"]

String n = ""
names.each{
    n += it + ","
}

println n
```

Output:

```
myname,yourname,theirname,allnames,
```

How do I get rid of the trailing comma?

Comment: See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25793522/656912) on implementing the Oxford comma in Groovy, as well as the related [code golf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37653/3019).

Answer (score 19):

```
names.join(",")
```