# How do I get a single string with an Oxford comma in Groovy?

Tags: string, list, groovy, coding-style

I'm new to Groovy and am trying to sort out some of the idioms that make it attractive. For example, I'd like to take a list of strings and return a single properly punctuated string built from the list, with each element quoted.

Roughly, the literal (rather generic, and probably brain-dead) approach would be

```
def temp = things.collect({"\'${it}\'"})
switch (things.size()) {
    case 1:
        result = temp[0]
        break
    case 2:
        result = temp.join(" and ")
        break
    default:
        result = temp.take(temp.size()-1).join(", ") + ", and " + temp[-1]
        break
}
```

Is there a more Groovy way to do this that takes advantage of the language's idioms?

Comment: @cfrick: [Good idea](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37653/3019)!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my solution below. It seems to be complicated at first sight, but it's quite simple. Feel free to ask if you've got any questions.

```
def oxfordComma(list) {
    list = list.collect { "'$it'" }
    list.size in [1,2] ? list.join(' and ') : list[0..-2].join(', ') + ', and ' + list[-1]
}

assert oxfordComma(['one']) == "'one'"
assert oxfordComma(['one', 'two']) == "'one' and 'two'"
assert oxfordComma(['one', 'two', 'three']) == "'one', 'two', and 'three'"
```

And shorter version for code golf below ;-)

```
oxfordComma = { list ->
    list.collect{"'$it'"}.with { it.size in [1,2] ? it.join(' and ') : it[0..-2].join(', ') + ', and ' + it[-1] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little too long, but hey:

```
oxford = { list ->
  list.collect { "'$it'" }.with { 
    size() > 1 ? 
      (take(size() - 1) << "and " + last()).join(size() == 2 ? " " : ", ") : it[0]
  }
}

assert oxford(["a", "b"]) == "'a' and 'b'"
assert oxford(["a"]) == "'a'"
assert oxford(["a", "b", "c"]) == "'a', 'b', and 'c'"
```

Feels like code golf :-)

Answer (score 1):

`take` is fine, but a range is shorter.  using the same code for the `switch` `case 1` and `case 2` turns the switch into an if. `with` saves you the temp-var.

```
    def oxford = {
            it.collect({"'$it'"}).with{
                    it.size() < 3 ? it.join(' and ') : "${it[0..-2].join(', ')}, and ${it[-1]}"
            }
    }

    assert oxford(['Larry']) == '\'Larry\''
    assert oxford(['Larry', 'Jeff']) == '\'Larry\' and \'Jeff\''
    assert oxford(['Larry', 'Jeff', 'Leon']) == '\'Larry\', \'Jeff\', and \'Leon\''
```

Answer (score 0):

(This question is quite subjective for Stack O.)

My answer uses the meta-class functionality (and other minor features). The solution is not brief in implementation, but is brief in usage (and idiomatic, in the sense of writing a framework):

```
a=['oxford','cambridge']
println a.toString()

*prints* >> 'oxford' and 'cambridge'
```

Solution:

```
// quote
def q = {"'$it'"}

// apply Oxford for N > 2
def f = {it[0..-2].join(", ") + ", and " + it[-1]}

// map list size to Oxford function (N > 2 is default)
def fmap = [:].withDefault{f}
fmap[0] = {""}
fmap[1] = {"${it[0]}"}
fmap[2] = {"${it[0]} and ${it[1]}"}

// re-define toString() to call Oxford function from map
// (with quoted items)
ArrayList.metaClass.toString = { ->
fmap[ delegate.size() ].call( delegate.collect{q(it)} )
}
```

Example usage:

```
a=[] ; println a.toString()
a=['oxford'] ; println a.toString()
a=['oxford','cambridge'] ; println a.toString()
a=['oxford','cambridge','comma','space'] ; println a.toString()
```

Output from examples (_ denotes empty string):

```
_
'oxford'
'oxford' and 'cambridge'
'oxford', 'cambridge', 'comma', and 'space'
```